# Generating SAS token from service principal in DevOps pipeline (self-hosted)

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-cli, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I have the following script in a sel-fhosted Azure DevOps pipeline in order to copy build artefacts to Azure blob storage (static web site).

The task is as follows and I try to use [New-AzStorageContainerSASToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/new-azstoragecontainersastoken?view=azps-4.3.0), also the build step log tells it gets service principal. However, it appears I'm stuck about generating a SAS token for the container from the service principal the DevOps pipeline puts into the task so I could use it in `AzCopy`.

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Copy test'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'TestAccount (aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-bbbb-ffffffffffff)'
    addSpnToEnvironment: true
    scriptType: 'pscore'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      
      $ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "some123teststorage" -UseConnectedAccount
      $StartTime = Get-Date
      $EndTime = $startTime.AddDays(1)
      $sasToken = New-AzStorageContainerSASToken -Name "$web" -Permission rwd -StartTime $StartTime -ExpiryTime $EndTime -context $ctx
      azcopy copy "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\test-app\dist\" "$(destination_blob)" --put-md5 --recursive --overwrite=false --check-length=false --log-level=info
```

The error in the pipeline is

```
New-AzStorageContext : Context cannot be null.  Please log in using Connect-AzAccount.
```

All in all, in the DevOps pipeline log it is noted

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin\az.cmd" cloud set -n AzureCloud"
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin\az.cmd" login --service-principal -u *** "--password=***" --tenant *** --allow-no-subscriptions"
[
  {
    "cloudName": "AzureCloud",
    "homeTenantId": "***",
    "id": "<snip>",
    "isDefault": true,
    "managedByTenants": [],
    "name": "TestAccount",
    "state": "Enabled",
    "tenantId": "***",
    "user": {
      "name": "***",
      "type": "servicePrincipal"
    }
  }
]
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin\az.cmd" account set --subscription <snip>"
"C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'C:\azuredevops\agent\_work\_temp\azureclitaskscript1593799829465.ps1'"
***
New-AzStorageContext : Context cannot be null.  Please log in using Connect-AzAccount.
```

It is notable `Azure file copy` task in the release pipeline works. However, I would like do this straight from the build pipeline for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to generate the SAS token for a container in the Azure CLI task, please use Azure CLI command [`az storage container generate-sas`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-container-generate-sas) instead of the powershell command.

Make sure the service principal related to the service connection has a role in the `Access control (IAM)` of your storage account or subscription, e.g. `Storage Blob Data Contributor`, if not, follow this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/quickstart-assign-role-user-portal) to add it.

**Sample:**

```
az storage container generate-sas \
    --account-name <storage-account> \
    --name <container> \
    --permissions acdlrw \
    --expiry <date-time> \
    --auth-mode login \
    --as-user
```

For more details, refer to this doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-user-delegation-sas-create-cli#create-a-user-delegation-sas-for-a-container

Comment: I'll accept this. I noticed this works when using the new "combined" pipeline. While the  current pipeline is separate CI and then a release pipeline, I think I can refactor. Put this here for other people that may have similar problems.